# Navigation Drawer with Multiple activities. - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am developing my mobile application through Android Studio. My application's launcher activity is a `SplashScreen`. The `SplashScreen` with `Intent` navigates to my `HomeActivity`. I tried the code from [***this***](http://androiddeveloperdemo.blogspot.com/2014/08/android-navigation-drawer-with-multiple.html?showComment=1420507502688#c9185652031046966495) blog, so that I can have a navigation drawer but between activities not fragments.

In `Splashscreen` and `HomeActivity` activities, I don't want to have this drawer. In `HomeActivity` there is a button (`signin`). When you press it you will navigate NORMALLY to `SearchActivity` which is the first page in which I want to have my Navigate Drawer.

In the example above, the launcher activity is the `BaseActivity`. Because I don't want `BaseActivity` to be my launcher activity, as I described, I navigate to `BaseActivity`, after clicking the `signin` button inside the `HomeActivity`.

---

My HomeActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;
import common.activities.SampleActivityBase;
import common.logger.Log;
import common.logger.LogFragment;
import common.logger.LogWrapper;
import common.logger.MessageOnlyLogFilter;


public class HomeActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

    public static final String TAG = "HomeActivity";

    // Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
    private boolean mLogShown;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageButton send = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.signin);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SlidingTabsColorsFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsColorsFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem logToggle = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_log);
        logToggle.setVisible(findViewById(R.id.sample_output) instanceof ViewAnimator);
        logToggle.setTitle(mLogShown ? "hide" : "show");

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//        switch(item.getItemId()) {
//            case R.id.menu_toggle_log:
//                mLogShown = !mLogShown;
//                ViewAnimator output = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.sample_output);
//                if (mLogShown) {
//                    //output.setDisplayedChild(1);
//                } else {
//                    //output.setDisplayedChild(0);
//                }
//                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
//                return true;
//        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /** Create a chain of targets that will receive log data */
    @Override
    public void initializeLogging() {
        // Wraps Android's native log framework.
        LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
        // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
        Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);

        // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
        MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
        logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);

        // On screen logging via a fragment with a TextView.
//        LogFragment logFragment = (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//                .findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
//        msgFilter.setNext(logFragment.getLogView());
//
//        Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
    }

}
```

---

My BaseActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author dipenp
 *
 * This activity will add Navigation Drawer for our application and all the code related to navigation drawer.
 * We are going to extend all our other activites from this BaseActivity so that every activity will have Navigation Drawer in it.
 * This activity layout contain one frame layout in which we will add our child activity layout.
 */
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     *  Frame layout: Which is going to be used as parent layout for child activity layout.
     *  This layout is protected so that child activity can access this
     *  */
    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;

    /**
     * ListView to add navigation drawer item in it.
     * We have made it protected to access it in child class. We will just use it in child class to make item selected according to activity opened.
     */

    protected ListView mDrawerList;

    /**
     * List item array for navigation drawer items.
     * */
    protected String[] listArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };

    /**
     * Static variable for selected item position. Which can be used in child activity to know which item is selected from the list.
     * */
    protected static int position;

    /**
     *  This flag is used just to check that launcher activity is called first time
     *  so that we can open appropriate Activity on launch and make list item position selected accordingly.
     * */
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;

    /**
     *  Base layout node of this Activity.
     * */
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    /**
     * Drawer listner class for drawer open, close etc.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        /**
         * As we are calling BaseActivity from manifest file and this base activity is intended just to add navigation drawer in our app.
         * We have to open some activity with layout on launch. So we are checking if this BaseActivity is called first time then we are opening our first activity.
         * */
        if(isLaunch){
            /**
             *Setting this flag false so that next time it will not open our first activity.
             *We have to use this flag because we are using this BaseActivity as parent activity to our other activity.
             *In this case this base activity will always be call when any child activity will launch.
             */
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     *
     * Launching activity when any list item is clicked.
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {

        /**
         * We can set title & itemChecked here but as this BaseActivity is parent for other activity,
         * So whenever any activity is going to launch this BaseActivity is also going to be called and
         * it will reset this value because of initialization in onCreate method.
         * So that we are setting this in child activity.
         */
//      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
//      setTitle(listArray[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities.

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                break;
            case 1:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                break;
            case 2:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                break;
            case 3:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                break;
            case 4:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
}
```

---

My SearchActivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class SearchActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         *  We will not use setContentView in this activty
         *  Rather than we will use layout inflater to add view in FrameLayout of our base activity layout*/

        /**
         * Adding our layout to parent class frame layout.
         */
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_search, frameLayout);

        /**
         * Setting title and itemChecked
         */
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);

        //((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
    }
}
```

---

drawer_list_item.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"/>
```

---

And my navigation_drawer_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

That is my whole code related to what I am trying to do.

When I press the `signin` button inside the `HomeActivity` I get these errors:

```
01-06 13:39:45.563  17197-17197/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all, PID: 17197
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.BaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:92)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: indicate `BaseActivity.java:92`

Comment: It's this line:         `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: `getActionBar()` is null in your code, if you min sdk is lower than 11 you need use `getSupportActionBar()`, if min sdk is bigger that 11 check theme, maybe you remove or hide that, if this don't help you too search about ``getActionBar()` return null`,

Comment: are you using actionbar app combat in your theme?? because if you do then you need to extend the ActionBarActivity and then use getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: My minsdk is 16. I opened the `styles.xml` and in the `MyActionBar` style, the `parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"` has error that it  can not resolve this symbol. Is there a possibility that I deleted something important related to styles and attributes? Because many other xml files had problems with the `@android ...` e.t.c and I just deleted their styles. But I don't know how to import these styles again in my project.

Comment: Yes @KostasMatrix this is my theme:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: so you say noActionBar and yet you are trying to getActionBar()?? add a toolbar perhaps and then use getSupportActionBar()

Comment: comment your static int position and try again. i think that this may cause the problem. The listview item click listener has already the position so you dont need to make it static..

Comment: In my Styles.xml, I changed AppTheme , and MyActionBar theme to have this parent: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` . In my BaseActivity.xml , I changed all the getActionBar to `getSupportActionBar()`.  Now, when I pressed for the first time the signin button, I get the toast `Position 0` something like this. When I  comment the static int position the array can't find the variable position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68277/discussion-between-kostasmatrix-and-marialena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the following:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected String[] listArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        //mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
            }
        });

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //use the support library in App Combat
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //in the line below you will always get the Selected position 0 because your isLaunch = true, so it will always give you this toast. If you think its unessecary remove it.
        if(isLaunch){
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }
```

Since Navigation Drawer works with `Fragments` try this approach:

```
protected Fragment openActivity(int position) {

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:{
                fragment =  new SearchActivity();
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                fragment = new A();
                break;
            }

            case 2:{
                fragment = new B();
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                fragment = new C();
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                fragment = new D();
                break;
            }

        }
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        return fragment;
    }
```

Use the `onOptionsItemSelected` method as such:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The onBackPressed method as such:

Remove the else statement because you dont want to press the back button and open the Drawer

```
/* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

Also Modify your SearchActivity to a Fragment since you would like to be the First fragment when drawer opens like:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View convertView = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView= getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: in the onOptionsItemSelected should I put this in the end? Because I got an error that it has no return. `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);`

Comment: I just editted one more thing. Instead of getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
use
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

Comment: It's working fine. Great and most important EASY solution. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

in base activty override setContentView() like this.

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.activity_base, null);
    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) mDrawerLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) mDrawerLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, mFrameLayout, true);
    super.setContentView(mDrawerLayout);

    //Your custom code
```

}

Comment: I put this in comments `     setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);
`

 I added your code outside the onCreate, but changed some names that were different. I didn't add any other code.

Comment: Some of the errrors:
`01-06 14:36:48.176  24882-24882/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all, PID: 24882
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.BaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
 ... `

Answer (score 0):

Can you call

> setContentView(R.layout. navigation_drawer_layout);

instead of

> setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

in the `BaseActivity`?

This error usually happens when you have error in accessing findViewById.  Simply comment out **mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);** to check if this is the problem.

Comment: I don't have a layout : `navigation_drawer_layout.xml`.  I also comment also the line that you said but the error remains:
`01-06 14:16:08.928  22231-22231/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all, PID: 22231
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.BaseActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(BaseActivity.java:222)
            at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2556)
           . . . `